# Is it possible to put a component into a handsontable cell?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

Here is my code:

```js
import {
  HotTable
} from '@handsontable/react';
import {
  registerAllModules
} from 'handsontable/registry';
import MonthPicker from '../util/monthPicker/MonthPicker';
import 'handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.css';
registerAllModules();
export default function TestReactDataSheet() {
   return (
        <HotTable
            data={[
                ["Caption", '', '', ''],
                [<MonthPicker />],
                ['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'],
                ['A3', '&nbsp;', 'C3', 'D3'],
            ]}
            cell={[ { row: 0, col: 0, className: 'htCenter'},{ row: 1, col: 0, className: 'htCenter' }]}
            columns={[
                {
                    renderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
                        if (row !== 1){
                            td.textContent=value;
                            td.className=cellProperties.className;
                        }else {                            

                        }
                        
                        return td;
                    }
                },
                {},
                {},
                {}
            ]}
            colHeaders={false}            
            mergeCells={
                [
                    { row: 0, col: 0, rowspan: 1, colspan: 4 },
                    { row: 1, col: 0, rowspan: 1, colspan: 4 },
                    { row: 2, col: 1, rowspan: 2, colspan: 1 }
                ]
            }
            height = "auto"
            rowHeaders = {false}
            licenseKey="non-commercial-and-evaluation"
            readOnly={true} 
        />
    );
}
```

I want to put the MonthPicker component into a cell, however, the above code does not work.

I have followed the instruction in this [page](https://handsontable.com/docs/react-data-grid/cell-renderer/) to create a cell renderer, unfortunately, the example just shows how to modify the DOM object, not the react component, how can I convert the react component into an HTML node?

I have tried to use ReactDOM and ReactDOMServer to convert the MonthPicker into HTML markup, but these objects just convert the MonthPicker into a string, the javascript is not working now.

If it is impossible, is there any workaround solution?

Comment: official docs is the best place to get started, this is the documentation you are looking for,  https://handsontable.com/docs/react-data-grid/cell-renderer/#declare-a-custom-renderer-as-a-component

Comment: A cell type is a combination of renderer, validator and editor, as mentioned https://handsontable.com/docs/javascript-data-grid/cell-type/ if you compose those for a cell it should be doable. Handsontable already has a date picker, so you could try to extend the DateEditor class first.